# CPU core stuck in kthread, in a custom driver

Tags: linux-kernel

When I insmod the ko that has a deadloop in the kernel thead, the kthread run on a cpu core and the core cannot run any other process any more. and the NMI watchdog is trigger more times: "NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 22s! [pradeep:1403]".

why?

the ko code is ( the code which I copy from the web maybe has errors and the ko cannot be rmmod (yes I know).) :

```c
#include<linux/init.h>
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/kthread.h>
#include<linux/sched.h>

struct task_struct *task;
int data;
int ret;

void zg___aaa(void)
{
    int a=0;
    while (a<1000)
        ++a;

    return;
}

int zg___thread_function(void *data)
{
  int var;
  var = 10;
  printk(KERN_INFO "IN THREAD FUNCTION");

  while(1) {
        zg___aaa();
  }

  return var;   
}

static int kernel_init(void)
{
   data = 20;
   printk(KERN_INFO"--------------------------------------------");

   task = kthread_run(&zg___thread_function,(void *)&data,"pradeep");
   printk(KERN_INFO"Kernel Thread : %s\n",task->comm);

   return 0;
}

static void kernel_exit(void)
{
   kthread_stop(task);
}

module_init(kernel_init);
module_exit(kernel_exit);
MODULE_AUTHOR("SHRQ");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

the kernel config file is too big to summit I can only put some related items:

```
~/build-linux$ cat ./.config | grep PREEMPT
CONFIG_PREEMPT_NOTIFIERS=y
# CONFIG_PREEMPT_NONE is not set
CONFIG_PREEMPT_VOLUNTARY=y
# CONFIG_PREEMPT is not set
```

I move the deadloop into kernel_init, the same as before.
and the error log from kernel:

```
[ 4463.800938] NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 23s! [insmod:1605]
[ 4463.800943] Modules linked in: testko(OE+) xt_CHECKSUM iptable_mangle  .......
[ 4463.800986] CPU: 0 PID: 1605 Comm: insmod Tainted: G           OEL  4.11.0-rc2+ #14
[ 4463.800987] Hardware name: Hewlett-Packard  /304Bh, BIOS 786H1 v01.13 07/14/2011
[ 4463.800988] task: ffff89c378773800 task.stack: ffffb18883264000
[ 4463.800992] RIP: 0010:kernel_init+0x2f/0x40 [testko]
[ 4463.800993] RSP: 0018:ffffb18883267cc8 EFLAGS: 00000286 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffff10
[ 4463.800994] RAX: 0000000000000012 RBX: ffffffffc06d6030 RCX: 0000000000000006
[ 4463.800995] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000086 RDI: ffff89c39bc0e0a0
[ 4463.800995] RBP: ffffb18883267cc8 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 000000000000030f
[ 4463.800996] R10: 0000000000000004 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffff89c3837038c0
[ 4463.800996] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffff89c37862e5a0 R15: ffffb18883267eb0
[ 4463.800997] FS:  00007feb6e1c45c0(0000) GS:ffff89c39bc00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[ 4463.800998] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[ 4463.800999] CR2: 00007feb6d717450 CR3: 000000020edc0000 CR4: 00000000000006f0
[ 4463.801000] Call Trace:
[ 4463.801006]  do_one_initcall+0x51/0x1b0
[ 4463.801009]  ? __vunmap+0x85/0xd0
[ 4463.801013]  ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0x15c/0x1c0
[ 4463.801014]  ? kfree+0x13b/0x180
[ 4463.801016]  do_init_module+0x60/0x1fa
[ 4463.801019]  load_module+0x22dd/0x2870
[ 4463.801021]  ? __symbol_put+0x40/0x40
[ 4463.801022]  SYSC_finit_module+0x96/0xd0
[ 4463.801024]  SyS_finit_module+0xe/0x10
[ 4463.801027]  entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x1a/0xa9
[ 4463.801028] RIP: 0033:0x7feb6d6aebf9
[ 4463.801028] RSP: 002b:00007ffca2026c48 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000139
[ 4463.801030] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000000003 RCX: 00007feb6d6aebf9
[ 4463.801030] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000558f2ec2c186 RDI: 0000000000000003
[ 4463.801031] RBP: 0000000000000086 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 00007feb6d96fe80
[ 4463.801031] R10: 0000000000000003 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000558f2fda0130
[ 4463.801032] R13: 0000000000000001 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 00007ffca2025acc
```

......

my question, why when deadloop in kernel mode, the preempted kernel scheduler  cannot preempt the deadloop code and switch to other thread? when the deadloop run in the user mode, the scheduler function nomarlly.

Comment: the kernel version is 4.11-rc

Comment: can you paste your complete kernel config?

Comment: ok, I will paste all the config file.

Comment: the kernel config file I taked from the fedora 24, and the 4.11-rc2 kernel should modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### First of all...

...using `kthread_stop` won't magically stop your thread. If you think about it, your kernel thread does not have any exit points, so it won't ever stop.

In order to stop your thread properly, you can use `kthread_should_stop`. I have added a little example here, showing this.

#### Core stuck

Now, about the issue you describe, where your core is stuck. My guess is that you are running a non-preemptible kernel. Non-preemptible kernels cannot context switch when running kernel code, which would explain what you've described.

For more information about kernel preemption, of course [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_preemption) knows something about it.

If you disable preemption in the kernel thread, you will stuck your core and get the same "NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup" warning. This can be tested with:

```c
int thread_fn(void *arg)
{
        preempt_disable();
        while (!kthread_should_stop())
                busyloop();
        preempt_enable();
        return 0;
}
```

#### Update, based on your config:

Your kernel configuration shows that your kernel has *voluntary preemption* enabled, but it's not fully preemptable:

```
CONFIG_PREEMPT_VOLUNTARY=y
# CONFIG_PREEMPT is not set
```

When a config says `CONFIG_PREEMPT is not set` it means such option is disabled. A kernel that is not fully preemptable, like yours, simply *can't re-schedule to another thread*, because it's explicitly configured to remove that feature.

You can use `cond_resched()` to re-schedule your thread explicitly, or you might also use `kernel_freezable_should_stop`. Like this:

```c
int thread_fn(void *arg)
{
        bool was_frozen;

        while (!kthread_freezable_should_stop(&was_frozen))
                busyloop();
        return 0;
}
```

#### How do you check your preemptible configuration

```
$ zcat /proc/config.gz | grep CONFIG_PREEMPT=
CONFIG_PREEMPT=y
```

#### My test driver

```c
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/kthread.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>

struct task_struct *task;

void busyloop(void)
{
    int a = 0;
    while (a < 1000)
        ++a;
}

int thread_fn(void *arg)
{
    bool was_frozen;

    while (!kthread_freezable_should_stop(&was_frozen))
        busyloop();
    return 0;
}

static int kernel_init(void)
{
    task = kthread_run(&thread_fn, NULL, "test");
    return 0;
}

static void kernel_exit(void)
{
    kthread_stop(task);
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL"); 
module_init(kernel_init);
module_exit(kernel_exit);
```

Comment: ~/build-linux$ cat ./.config | grep PREEMPT
CONFIG_PREEMPT_NOTIFIERS=y
# CONFIG_PREEMPT_NONE is not set
CONFIG_PREEMPT_VOLUNTARY=y
# CONFIG_PREEMPT is not set

Comment: tnks for your reply, my key question is why I deadloop in the kernel mode, the cpu is too busy to schedual other thread on the same core?

Comment: well, your config clearly don't have CONFIG_PREEMPT enabled (it says CONFIG_PREEMPT is not set). Therefore your kernel is not busy to schedule, but it does not support re-scheduling in kernel context. I will update my reply, hoping it's clearer to you.

Comment: @EzequielGarcia Build linux-next kernel for x86_64 and you will see that CONFIG_PREEMPT is set to  "NO", instead of this CONFIG_PREEMPT_VOLUNARY model is used. That doesn't mean that the kernel is not preemptible. So the problem is in something else.

Comment: @AlexHoppus, As far as I can see from reading what CONFIG_PREEMPT_VOLUNARY actually does, a kernel that is only voluntary preemptable, will only add a few might_sleep calls. Clearly, it cannot preempt a busy loop thread, that won't ever release the CPU.

Comment: @EzequielGarcia Actually, as I understand it adds rescheduling to might_sleep calls, but that may be done for increasing the amount of rescheduling points in order to reduce the latency (for time critical tasks like sound processing f.e.), but I don't sure that it forbids pereodic (by timer irq) in kernel context-switches at all. Could you provide the evidences ? I will try to read more.

Comment: @AlexHoppus I can be wrong but I believe the whole idea of CONFIG_PREEMPT is precisely to allow periodic re-scheduling, even when running in kernel mode. Plus, I'm actually testing this before I reply :-) Maybe this will help you understand what preemption means in Linux: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L3315, the comment mentions in details where schedule happens in each case.

Comment: @Ezequiel Garcia Ok, looks like it was my misunderstanding.

Comment: in the kernel kconfig, CONFIG_PREEMPT 
stand for "Preemptible Kernel (Low-Latency Desktop)" ; while CONFIG_PREEMPT_VOLUNARY stand for "Voluntary Kernel Preemption (Desktop)". I think all this two items enable the preempt . am I right?

Comment: if the kernel is not preempted,  why the deadloop run in user mode can be premmpted by other process or thread?

Comment: kconfig.preempt has the deatil info of this two config item. maybe the PREEMPT_VOLUNARY only make the preempt occur in user-mode and not kernel-mode? but I don't find any kernel source code about it.

Comment: #ifdef CONFIG_PREEMPT_VOLUNTARY
extern int _cond_resched(void);
# define might_resched() _cond_resched()
#else
# define might_resched() do { } while (0)
#endif
I got the correct code?

Comment: @shihhuangti You got it all wrong. The preemption model only applies to kernel context. User context has always been preemptable, and there is no way you can prevent it. In other words, a user mode thread can **always** be preempted. Kernel mode may be preempted, or not, depending on the preemption model.

Comment: @Ezequiel Garcia could you give a reference code which does what you have described? So if user space ctx is always preemptive and kernel ctx is not (suppose we use voluntary preemption), somewhere in scheduler_tick() call we should check if the user or kernel context was interrupted, and then perform context switch or not. I mean I can't find any signs of this. Or how does it work?

Comment: @AlexHoppus Well, comments in SO are not for general discussion and I think that exceedes this question (user mode preemption is not the question here). Here it goes anyway: user-space re-scheduling happens in syscall return or irq return. Let me pick nios2 arch because it's very simple to follow: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/nios2/kernel/entry.S#L290 You can see in `Luser_return` how `schedule()` is called if needed. That happens on any IRQ return (e.g. timer tick or whatever).

Comment: @AlexHoppus OK, I'm officially hooked :-) I checked on `schedule_tick` and it seems it's used to set the `TIF_NEED_RESCHED`. Then, the IRQ return in arch-specific path calls `schedule` if needed, just before it goes back to userspace, to perform the context switch.

Comment: @AlexHoppus , I think I got the right place:  usermode:entry64.S->retint_user->prepare_exit_to_usermode->exit_to_usermode_loop->test "_TIF_NEED_RESCHED" and schedule(); kernel mode : entry64.S->retint_kernel->will call preempt_schedule_irq but the calling code be controled by macro "CONFIG_PREEMPT". so Ezequiel Garcia is right : " The preemption model only applies to kernel context. User context has always been preemptable".

Comment: @Ezequiel Garcia you are right and tnks for your helping me to clarify this problem. CONFIG_PREEMPT_VOLUNTARY will enable the macro "might_resched" to call _cond_resched, and might_sleep will call might_resched, so CONFIG_PREEMPT_VOLUNTARY will enable might_sleep, and the macro "might_sleep" will be called many times within all the kernel , where the kernel can siwtch to other thread VOLUNTARily.  so CONFIG_PREEMPT_VOLUNTARY doesn't stand for "all the kernel code can be preempted".

Comment: @shihhuangti if this answer is enough for you to understand your problem, you could accept it.

Comment: @shihhuangti You need to click on the checkmark below the vote number. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work. Thank you sir!